# Ember 1.0.0 RESTAdapter failure

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I can't seem to track down the source of this error:

> Assertion failed: No model was found for '0'

The JSON is getting fetched by the server, but the app is erroring out before it gets sent to the template. The problem seems to be happening between the REST adapter and the router. The template renders error-free when I use the fixture adapter.

I'm using Ember and Handlebars versions 1.0.0.

Here's my App code:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("stories", { path: "/" }, function() {
        this.resource("boards", { path: "/boards"} )
    });
});

App.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('story');
    }
});

attr = DS.attr;

App.Story = DS.Model.extend({
    color: attr()
});
```

Handlebars templates

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{ outlet }}

    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stories">
    <ul>
        <li class="storyLine">
            <ul>
                <li id="colorSwatch"></li>
                <li class="board">+</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    {{#each model}}
        <li class="storyLine">
            <ul>
                <li id="colorSwatch" {{bindAttr class=story.color}}></li>
                <li class="board">dddd</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The response from the server probably isn't formatted correctly. The JSON needs to have a root that is the same name as your model. See: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root
Your response needs to look something like this:

```
{
  "story": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Formatting of JSON isn't the problem. When I paste the response into a variable and use that rather than getting it from the server all is fine.

Comment: Interesting. I was getting that same error, and adding a root to the json response fixed it for me. I'm not sure what else causes that error.

Comment: Aha - I was wrong, the JSON was the problem, as you suggested. I needed to use Active Model Serializer in Rails to satisfy the picky Ember RESTAdapter. Be warned!

Comment: I'm unable to modify the server data and am trying to follow the directions [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root) to override `extractDeleteRecord` in order to compensate, but it's not working.  Any ideas how to change the way RESTAdapter handles the "differently" formatted JSON payload?

Answer (score 0):

In your `bindAttr` you are using the object `story` therefore you should change your `{{#each}}` helper to make reference to that object:

```
...
{{#each story in model}}
  <li class="storyLine">
    <ul>
      <li id="colorSwatch" {{bindAttr class=story.color}}></li>
      <li class="board">dddd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
{{/each}}
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice thought but the problem seems to be with the adapter or router, not the template.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when shifting from an extended `FixtureAdapter` to an extended `RESTAdapter`. I was overwriting one of the `finder`- methods.

While there the `FixtureAdapter` was totally happy with an array of objects

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query, array) {
    return DS.PromiseArray.create({
        promise: new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var results = [];
            store.findAll('source').then(function(sources) {
                sources.forEach(
                    function (rootSource) {
                       results.push( store.createRecord( ... ));
                    }
                );
                resolve(results);
            },reject);
        })
    });
}
```

for the same method the `RESTAdapter` expected an object with key and array as value

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query, array) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var results = [];
        store.find('source').then(function(sources) {
            sources.forEach(
                function (rootSource) {
                    results.push({ ... });
                }
            );
            resolve({"connections":results});
        },reject);
    });
},
```

See the difference within the call of `resolve`.

Even it works to put an object into the array like in the `FixtureAdapter`, this will  result in the error 
`Assertion failed: You must use Ember.set() to access this property` later on when you try to change the objects properties.

For all of this, I'm using Ember 1.2.0, Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba.

Hope this helps...