# Ember-data: "no model found" while it's there

Tags: javascript, php, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to fetch model data from an RESTful backend. This works fine for the model "project", while for the model "canal" I only get an error message in the console saying:

> Assertion failed: Error while loading route: Error: No model was found
>   for '0'

Testing the API with curl works fine.

**router.js:**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("start", { path: "/" });
    this.route("projects", { path: "/projects" });
    this.route("canals", { path: "/canals" });
});


App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('project');
    }
});

App.CanalsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('canal');
    }
});
```

**models.js**

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    client: DS.attr('string'),
    comment: DS.attr('string'),
    project_number: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Canal = DS.Model.extend({
    pid:  DS.attr('number'),
    street: DS.attr('string'), 
    district: DS.attr('string'), 
    upper_inspection_point: DS.attr('string'), 
    lower_inspection_point: DS.attr('string'), 
    type: DS.attr('string'), 
    direction: DS.attr('string'), 
    profile: DS.attr('string'), 
    height: DS.attr('string'), 
    width: DS.attr('string'), 
    material: DS.attr('string'), 
    branch: DS.attr('number'), 
    length: DS.attr('number'),
    demolition_class: DS.attr('number'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    comment: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**app.js**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter,
});
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/index.php'
});
```

**Dependencies/Versions**

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.2.0 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.e1200068 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.2 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.0.3 ember-1.2.0.js:3231
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember-1.2.0.js:3231
Ember Debugger Active
```

**Edit**
It seems, that the backend (SlimPHP) delivers incompatible JSON response (http://jsfiddle.net/hk2ph/). I updated fetchAll() to fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) but I still get the numbered index:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM canals WHERE pid = :pid";
        try {
            $db = getConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":pid", $pid);
            $stmt->execute();
            $canals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $db = null;
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($canals);
            exit;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
            header("Content-Type: application/json");
            exit;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember 1.0.0 RESTAdapter failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644683/ember-1-0-0-restadapter-failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct style for building the JSON is:

```
$canals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now everything works fine, thanks for support!

Answer (score 4):

it's your json, it's returning a property that's making ember data think there is a type `0`, someting like this:

```
{
  canals:[
    {
      // stuff
    }],
  0: [
   {

   }]
}
```

Comment: You're right. I fetch the data from DB using PDO::fetchAll and this results in an array with numeric and named indexes Edit:
Example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hk2ph/

Comment: If you don't want to fix it server side, you can modify the json client side by using a custom serializer and overriding `extractArray ` https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: I already tried to fix the server side as described in the edit on the original post. But it seems that PDO::FEtCH_ASSOC ist nor working with my setup. I will try your soultion

Answer (score 1):

Check that your JSON api response is structured the way ember-data wants.  You should provide all resource data structured like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "title": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sources:
[Ember 1.0.0 RESTAdapter failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644683/ember-1-0-0-restadapter-failure)